# Android:Cannot logout from facebook and pass status

Tags: android, facebook, string

Problem1:When i click login button i can log in,give status.but when i press logout button it does not logout.So,how will i logout from facebook?

Problem2:I got a string str.I want to pass it in facebook's textfield (like we send messages by intent).How  will i do that.

main class:
       `

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static String APP_ID = "xxxxxxx"; 

private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

ImageButton btnFbLogin;
ImageButton btnFbLogout;
Button btnPostToWall;
String str="I want this to pass";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnFbLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
    btnFbLogout = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fbLogout);
    btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });


    btnFbLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            logoutFromFacebook();
        }
    });

    btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postToWall();
        }
    });



}


public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();


                        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {


                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}





public void postToWall() {

    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}
public void logoutFromFacebook() {
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        btnFbLogout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}

    }`
```

when i click the logout button it says:
`

```
      08-14 14:46:59.849: D/Image Button(284): button Clicked
      08-14 14:46:59.869: D/Facebook-Util(284): GET URL: https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php? method=auth.expireSession&format=json
      08-14 14:47:00.399: D/Logout from Facebook(284): {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid application ID.","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"auth.expireSession"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

`

Comment: have you tried answer?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the latest Facebook SDK 3.0. Also in that the login and logout functionality is handled by the Facebook SDK, so once you have logged in the button changes to Logout.

Comment: Still if you want to stick to this deprecated SDK you can use the following code to logout of Facebook : SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();      SessionStore.clear(con);
 Util.clearCookies(con);        SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520450/how-can-i-logout-from-facebook-when-i-click-logout-button/11520524#11520524

Comment: Just open inside the facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2 folder. Then copy the src and res folder in the facebook folder. Now paste it into your project.

Comment: @Arshad Parwez my code shows errors with Facebook SDK 3.0.2 .In your second solution: it shows error in SessionEvents. In suggestion it says to create class or constant,veriable etc.Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @BuppyRahat : You are just messing up everything. If you want to use the SessionEvents & SessionStore classes, then you need to use the deprecated SDK. There is no such class in the new Facebook SDK, it has been replaced with a Session class

Answer (score 0):

just clear sharedprefrence and clear cookig to logout from facebook

```
btnFbLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
        Util.clearCookies(youractivity.this);

        // your sharedPrefrence
        Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("MYFB_TOKEN",    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

OR

See this [How can i logout from facebook when i click logout button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520450/how-can-i-logout-from-facebook-when-i-click-logout-button/11520524#11520524)

Comment: Thanks.It shows error on  SessionStore. In suggestion it says to create class or constant,veriable etc.

Comment: First i set Context context=MainActivity.this; then used your code.nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

use this it is working for me

```
facebook.logout(this);
```

in Facebook SDK `Facebook.java`

```
public String logout(Context context) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
   Util.clearCookies(context);
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
   String response = request(b);
   setAccessToken(null);
   setAccessExpires(0);
   return response;
}
```